# Entity Framework tree structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, tree

I have an entity called Field, which looks like:

**Field.cs**

```
class Field
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So fields would look like a simple list like this:

```
1 : First Name
2 : Last Name
3 : Gender
4 : Passport
5 : Driver License
6 : Issued
7 : Expired
```

For each of another entity called Batch, I want to have an arbitrary tree of fields, that might look like this:

**First Batch**

```
     First Name   |      Last Name      |       Passport         |      Gender
                                        |  Issued    |   Expired |
```

or this:

**Second Batch**

```
     First Name   |      Last Name      |      Gender      |      Driver License    |
                                                           |  Issued    |   Expired |
```

or any other tree of fields, where users would type different values for each field (some fields would just be headings, like Passport, for example)

So my fields are just a list of elements that can be reused, having any sort of relationship between them based on the batch. My idea was to have the batch entity look like:

**Batch.cs**

```
class Batch 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Fields { get; set; }
     // other data...
}
```

Where fields is a JSON tree that would look like this for the "First Batch":

```
{ 1, 2, 4: { 6, 7 }, 3 }
```

And like this for the second batch:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 5: { 6, 7 } }
```

Batches could even have more deeply nested fields like this:

```
|             Passport             |
|     Issued      |     Expired    |
| Month  | Year   | Month  | Year  |
```

Is this the best way to store a relationship like this in the EF? Should I avoid the JSON field and normalize my data? If so, how would I go about saving an arbitrary tree relationship using EF model-first?

Comment: You don't tell how you plan to store the data, you only show their structure. What would the data model look like?

Comment: Since this is model-first, EF would generate the table, and a batch record would exactly like described: 
Id: 1 - Fields: "{ 1, 2, 4: { 6, 7 }, 3 }"
I would then use the json from the string to display the fields on a batch. 
Maybe you mean how I would store the user-entered data, and in that case, I was planning on storing that on a nosql database, following basically the same json structure with a key-value pair for each field.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create two classes document and state like this

```
class Batch
{
 public int BatchId { get; set; }
 public string BachFirstName{ get; set; }
 public string BachLastName{ get; set; }
 public string BachGender{ get; set; }
 public Document BachDocument{ get; set; }
}

class Document
{
 public int DocId { get; set; }
 public string DocDesignation{ get; set; }
 public State DocState{ get; set; }
}


class State
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string StateDesignation{ get; set; }
 public date StateDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, as the fields are a dynamic list created by users, which will then associate them with the batch, forming the structure mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it dynamic, you need to use Key-Value tables like this.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    }

    class User
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    }

    class Batch
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BatchId { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(256)]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(512)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Batch> Children { get; set; }
    }

    class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>
    {
        protected override void Seed(Db context)
        {
            var user = new User();
            context.Users.Add(user);
            user.Batches = new List<Batch>();
            user.Batches.AddRange(new List<Batch>
            {
                new Batch {Key = "First Name", Value = "John"},
                new Batch {Key = "Last Name", Value = "Smith"},
                new Batch {Key = "Passport", Children = new List<Batch>
                {
                    new Batch {Key = "Issued", Value = "2014-02-03"},
                    new Batch {Key = "Expired", Value = "2015-02-03"},
                }}
            });
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new Initializer());
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Batches.ToList(), Formatting.Indented));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generate `Schema` of this table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batches](
    [BatchId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [Batch_BatchId] [int] NULL,
    [User_UserId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Batches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BatchId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Batches]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Batches_dbo.Batches_Batch_BatchId] FOREIGN KEY([Batch_BatchId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Batches] ([BatchId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Batches] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Batches_dbo.Batches_Batch_BatchId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Batches]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Batches_dbo.Users_User_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([User_UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Batches] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Batches_dbo.Users_User_UserId]
GO
```

Where `[User_UserId]` is not `NULL` for the root batches and `[Batch_BatchId]` is not `NULL` for the nested ones. Going through this tree is up to you and your business logic.